# Toggle SQL show details

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

I have create a button and run sql to show all onleave details:

```
<input type="button" style="cursor: pointer;width:180px;" value="Show All Onleave Detail">
```

How to create a toggle function? Where at first the sql run as:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM onleave where DATE(o_to) >= CURDATE() ORDER BY o_from DESC";
```

When I click the button, the sql will change to:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM onleave ORDER BY o_from DESC";
```

Comment: If you want that to work without page refresh look into AJAX

Comment: If with page refresh?

Comment: With page fresh its easier, roughly: create a form that calls the same page, have the button to submit the form, hold the current toogle status in a PHP session and alternate the used SQL based on the toogle status